# Browser support in Windows XP

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser, windows-xp, opera

What are highest version of browser (Google Chrome, Opera) supported by windows XP (32 bit & 64 bit) ?

I found IE7 is highest version supported by XP but can't find for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download them from here...

[Chrome Download Page](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html)

[Opera Download Page](http://www.opera.com/computer/windows)

I am sure that downloaders will pick suitable highest version for you...

Comment: Thanks for answer. All latest version are supported by XP itselt.